# Convergence and estimate of improper integral involving function $\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}$.

Tags: inequality, improper-integrals

Study the convergence of the improper integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left\{\frac{\sin(\pi(x-t))}{\pi(x-t)}\right\}\Biggl|_{x=n}\ \cdot \ \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left\{\frac{\sin(\pi(x-t))}{\pi(x-t)}\right\}\Biggl|_{x=m} dt$$
for $n,m,k\in\mathbb N$, and if it is convergent to give an its estimate from above.

My attempt: I have tried to use the relationship
$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left\{\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}\right\}=\pi^k\int_0^1 s^k \cos\left(s\pi x+k\frac{\pi}{2}\right)ds$$
but without success.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps. No guarantee about computational errors.

Let $\tilde{f}(\omega )$ be the Fourier transform of $\sin (\pi
x)/(\pi x)$. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\sin (\pi (x-t))}{\pi (x-t)} &=&\int d\omega \exp [i\omega (x-t)]
\tilde{f}(\omega ) \\
\partial _{x}^{k}\frac{\sin (\pi (x-t))}{\pi (x-t)} &=&\int d\omega (i\omega
)^{k}\exp [i\omega (x-t)]\tilde{f}(\omega )
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dt\int d\omega _{1}(i\omega _{1})^{k}\exp
[i\omega _{1}(x_{1}-t)]\tilde{f}(\omega _{1})\int d\omega _{2}(i\omega
_{2})^{k}\exp [i\omega _{2}(x_{2}-t)]\tilde{f}(\omega _{2}) \\
&=&\int d\omega _{1}\int d\omega _{2}(i\omega _{1})^{k}(i\omega
_{2})^{k}\exp [i(\omega _{1}x_{1}+\omega _{2}x_{2})]2\pi \delta (\omega
_{1}+\omega _{2})\tilde{f}(\omega _{1})\tilde{f}(\omega _{2}) \\
&=&2\pi \int d\omega _{1}(i\omega _{1})^{k}(-i\omega _{1})^{k}\exp [i(\omega
_{1}(x_{1}-x_{2})]\tilde{f}(\omega _{1})\tilde{f}(-\omega _{1}) \\
&=&2\pi \int d\omega _{1}\omega _{1}^{2k}\exp [i(\omega _{1}(x_{1}-x_{2})]
\tilde{f}(\omega _{1})\tilde{f}(-\omega _{1})
\end{eqnarray*}